# Save web form values prior to redirect to login page with Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using Spring security 4.0. I have a basic web form which submits by POST to /SaveForm. In order to do this you have to be an authenticated user.

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/SaveForm" access="isAuthenticated()" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
```

My form-login is as follows where LoginAuthenticationSuccessHandler which implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler.

```
<security:form-login login-page="/login"
        authentication-failure-url="/login" username-parameter="email"
        password-parameter="password"
        authentication-success-handler ref="LoginAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
```

Not sure if it's relevant but I'm also using CustomAuthenticationProvider bean which implements AuthenticationProvider (which just returns true or false).

```
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider
        ref="CustomAuthenticationProvider">
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Once on the login page I'm saving the header "Referer" so I can redirect back to that page after. See Controller below

```
@RequestMapping("/login")
public String login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {

    String referringURL = request.getHeader("Referer");
    session.setAttribute("referring_url", referringURL);
```

Then in my LoginAuthenticationSuccessHandler class ( which implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler ) I redirect back to the original web form

```
redirectURL = (String) session.getAttribute("referring_url");
response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
```

This "hack" works but it seems that in Spring you can automatically redirect back to the original page that was requested without this. I can't seem to configure it however. My problem is the original form values are lost and I can't figure out where to save them. Once I submit to /SaveForm Spring security intercepts as expected but then how can I save the form values? I want to be able to re-populate the form with the values they typed before being made to authenticate.

Comment: For me the default wasn't working. I'm sure I have some broken configuration or something. Hopefully someone has come up with a way to save the form values, seems like a very common workflow.

Comment: Spring Security provides this out-of-the-box (it saves the full original request). The fact that you are trying to hack something together yourself breaks it. One of the things that is breaking this is the fact you have your own `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` instead of using the default. It also doesn't help that you have your own login mechanism. Basically you are trying to work around Spring Security and still expect it to work. Stop working around Spring Security and use it.

Comment: Spring allows you to customize it's framework, allowing you to override what you need. I'm using my own AuthenticationSuccessHandler to make additional DB calls needed. Surely this isn't such a radical notion.

Comment: As M. Deinum wrote, it is the default and he is also right with the HTTP `POST` data. I just found the documentation: *If a SavedRequest is found in the RequestCache (as set by the ExceptionTranslationFilter to record the original destination before the authentication process commenced), a redirect will be performed to the Url of that original destination. The SavedRequest object will remain cached and be picked up when the redirected request is received (See SavedRequestAwareWrapper).*